# Is the Android Application Manager Infallible?

Tags: malware, android, virus-removal

When the Android Application Manager reports that an app has been uninstalled, or an app does not or no longer appears in the Application Manager list under any category (installed, running, etc.), is it definitely uninstalled and removed from the system? Or can some just pretend or avoid appearing in the app manager at all?

*This could be asked on the Android stack, but there are some obviously serious security implications involved here, andnunder the circumstances, would only be done by a malicious program. I'll let the mods decide.

Comment: If the malware had root, all bets are off.

Comment: "Infallible" is a very, very, very strong term.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a security question but I guess that is down to the choice of words. Please edit to clarify what you want to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android apps are by definition the entities that may be managed by Application Manager. So if uninstalled, it is really gone.

But.

Not all apps can be uninstalled. This includes system apps that are typically preinstallled on the device. It is not impossible to add a system app later, having acquired root access (maybe, under the hood; maybe, temporarily; maybe, without the owner's consent). Also some apps become "device management" and require special permission to be uninstalled.

On the other hand, apps are not the only code that runs on the device. Even after a malicious app is completely uninstalled, it can leave active executables that can potentially do anything - including reinstalling the app when you don't pay attention.

Comment: These questions apply to non-rooted devices. I got the secondary executable / restoration part and I'm also guessing they could obfuscate the name that appears in the manager. Tinfoil Hat Time: is it possible for the app to automatically remove itself when opening the Application Manager, or even sooner as in when the Settings panel is first opened, and then re-install afterwards?

Comment: The 'name' that appears in Application Manager can be just anything. Probably Play Store has some filters for approving the apps that are distributed officially, but if the app is sideloaded - there is no control.

Comment: I don't think that an app can get itself invisibly uninstalled: normally, AM pops up a message box. This applies to the moment when the user opens AM or Settings. But a malicious app could patch the system and/or AM, after acquiring root access.